# Erro anormal ao entrar em uma pagina MethodInfo.Invoke "Erro na contagem dos parametros"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Estou chamando a função a seguir porem ela da este problema "Erro na contagem dos parametros" quando executa:

```
url = (string)miScriptReference_GetUrl.Invoke(this, new object[] { scriptManager, value, false });
```

Codigo:

```
public string GetUrl(ScriptManager scriptManager)
        {
            string url = string.Empty;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path))
            {
                try
                {
                    PropertyInfo piScriptManager_IControl = scriptManager.GetType().GetProperty("Control", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    MethodInfo miScriptReference_GetUrl = typeof(ScriptReference).GetMethod("GetUrl", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    Type typeIControl = Type.GetType(piScriptManager_IControl.PropertyType.AssemblyQualifiedName.ToString(), false, true);
                    //object value = Convert.ChangeType(piScriptManager_IControl.PropertyType, typeIControl);
                    object value = piScriptManager_IControl.GetValue(scriptManager, null);
                    url = (string)miScriptReference_GetUrl.Invoke(this, new object[] { scriptManager, value, false });

                    /*return base.GetUrl(scriptManager, false); //Ajax 3.5*/
                    //MethodInfo miGetScriptResourceUrl = typeof(ScriptManager).GetMethod("GetScriptResourceUrl", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                    //Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                    //url = (string)miGetScriptResourceUrl.Invoke(scriptManager, new object[] { Name, asm });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                url = scriptManager.ResolveClientUrl(Path);
            }
            return url;
        }
```

Esse problema começou após migrar a vs do .net da 2.0 para 4.7

Comment: Não vi nada do erro em si porque na forma apresentada não me motivou a ver, mas se você tirar esse `try-catch` já ajuda bem seu código ficar melhor, porque ele faz nada a não ser estragar o *stack* trace*. Nunca use algo que não sabe para que serve e o que está fazendo. Isso já ajudará mais com seu erro atual e todos os outros que virão. Mas vejo várias coisas bem ruins nesse código, acho que ele pode ser muito mais simples e provavelmente nem teria esse erro.

Comment: Já que você diz que poderia ser mais simples, por favor me mostre na resposta uma forma mais simples e que me ajude a resolver... ps: estou fazendo a migração esse código deve ter uns 10 anos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema deixando a função assim!

```
public string GetUrl(ScriptManager scriptManager)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Path))
    {
        return base.GetUrl(scriptManager, false);
    }
    else
    {
        return scriptManager.ResolveClientUrl(Path);
    }
}
```